# Настройка сетевых интерфейсов Windows Server 2019 v1809

Tags: сеть, hyper-v

Сервер работает на виртуальной машине. Включена виртуализация Hyper-V. Есть несколько созданных виртуальных адаптеров и vSwitch. Пытаюсь выполнить команду:

```
PS C:\> Set-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 5 -AddressFamily IPv4 -Forwarding Enabled
Set-NetIPInterface : Element not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 5 -AddressFamily IPv4 -Forwarding  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPInter...ystemName = ""):ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPInterface) [Set-NetIPInterface]
   , CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1168,Set-NetIPInterface
```

Хотя:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 5 -AddressFamily IPv4

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
5       vEthernet (Ethernet0)           IPv4                  1450              15 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Дополнительно:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4 -ifIndex 5 | Select-Object -Property *


Store                           : ActiveStore
AddressFamily                   : IPv4
Forwarding                      : Disabled
ClampMss                        : Disabled
Advertising                     : Disabled
NeighborUnreachabilityDetection : Enabled
RouterDiscovery                 : ControlledByDHCP
NeighborDiscoverySupported      : Yes
ManagedAddressConfiguration     : Enabled
OtherStatefulConfiguration      : Enabled
WeakHostSend                    : Disabled
WeakHostReceive                 : Disabled
IgnoreDefaultRoutes             : Disabled
AdvertiseDefaultRoute           : Disabled
ForceArpNdWolPattern            : Disabled
DirectedMacWolPattern           : Disabled
EcnMarking                      : AppDecide
Dhcp                            : Disabled
ConnectionState                 : Connected
AutomaticMetric                 : Enabled
ifIndex                         : 5
ifAlias                         : vEthernet (Ethernet0)
Caption                         :
Description                     :
ElementName                     :
InstanceID                      :
CommunicationStatus             :
DetailedStatus                  :
HealthState                     :
InstallDate                     :
Name                            : ?55<55;
OperatingStatus                 :
OperationalStatus               :
PrimaryStatus                   :
Status                          :
StatusDescriptions              :
AvailableRequestedStates        :
EnabledDefault                  : 2
EnabledState                    :
OtherEnabledState               :
RequestedState                  : 12
TimeOfLastStateChange           :
TransitioningToState            : 12
CreationClassName               :
SystemCreationClassName         :
SystemName                      :
NameFormat                      :
OtherTypeDescription            :
ProtocolIFType                  :
ProtocolType                    :
AliasAddresses                  :
GroupAddresses                  :
LANID                           :
LANType                         :
MACAddress                      :
MaxDataSize                     :
OtherLANType                    :
AdvertisedRouterLifetime        : 00:30:00
BaseReachableTime               : 30000
CompartmentId                   : 1
CurrentHopLimit                 : 0
DadRetransmitTime               : 1000
DadTransmits                    : 3
InterfaceAlias                  : vEthernet (Ethernet0)
InterfaceIndex                  : 5
InterfaceMetric                 : 15
IsolationId                     : 0
LowestIfNetLuid                 : 1689399800627200
NlMtu                           : 1450
ReachableTime                   : 20000
RetransmitTime                  : 1000
PSComputerName                  :
CimClass                        : ROOT/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetIPInterface
CimInstanceProperties           : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties             : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

В чём дело? Куда смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снимается, перезагрузка сервера проблему решила.